# assigning an i.d to an element using JSON

Tags: jquery, json

i was just wondering if there would be any way to assign an i.d to a checkbox in JSON, so that i can use this i.d in JQuery to ensure that i'm taking some action when a checkbox is selected/checked. this checkbox has been created using JSON. if there is a way to assign an i.d to the checkbox created, then it would be easier for me to use JQuery and assign a 'listener' sort of action when the checkbox is selected. all i want to do is that, when the checkbox with the label 'I would like to provide input' is selected, i would like to display a textbox for the user to enter the input path. if the second check box with the label 'I would not like to provide input' is selected, then no textbox is displayed.

```
"window6": {
    "true": {
        "label": "I would like to provide input",
        "isEditable": "false",
        "name": "check_1",
        "type": "checkbox"
    },
    "false": {
        "label": "I would not like to provide input",
        "isEditable": "false",
        "name": "check_2",
        "type": "checkbox"
    }
},
```

Comment: you should show existing code. also, id/ID is simply id, not i.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign an ID to an element using jQuery, you can simply do so using the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$(":checkbox").attr("id", "yourId");
```

But when looking at your question, you're dynamically creating checkboxes and you want to add the ID in order to create a listener. You can better create it together when the DOM element is created, so the parser doesn't need to search the DOM in order to find the just created element. Example:

```
var elem = $("<input type='checkbox'>Checkbox</input>");
elem.click(function() {
    alert("clicked!"); 
});
elem.appendTo($("body"));
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXczL/).

Comment: hey, thanks for the prompt response. the solution provided by you seems to be okay, but i'm unable to append the checkbox to the 'window6' object, which is a part of many other such objects(keys). the hierarchy is something like this: